# Pentaho Data Integration, change log format

Tags: logging, log4j, pentaho, kettle

In PDI, the standard format of a log is like this:

e.g:

> 2016/06/01 11:18:32 - Check - Files exist

I want to find a solution to change `-` to a  (space)

Answer (score 2):

It is hard coded [here](https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-kettle/blob/c65c88abcae13625e3bc8ddeef7337cfb1927ae1/plugins/log4j/core/src/main/java/org/pentaho/di/core/logging/Log4jKettleLayout.java#L37), so can be only changed by changing that string literal and recompiling.